# English Sentences to Pig Latin

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define isvowel(v) (v=='a' || v=='e' || v=='i' || v=='o' || v=='u')

int main()
{
    char word[80];
    char exit;
    int length,x,y,z;

    printf("\nTranslating English words to Pig Latin\n\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter your English word:");
        scanf("%s",word);
        length = strlen(word);
        for(y=0;y<length;y++)
        if(isvowel(word[y]))
        {
            x=y;
            break;
        }
        for(;x<length;x++)
            printf("%c",word[x]);
        for(z=0;z<y;z++)
            printf("%c",word[z]);

        printf("ay");
        printf("\n\nPress ~ to exit\n\nEnter your word:");
        exit=getch();
    }
    while(exit!='~');

    return(0);
}
```

I have code written in C that works but only for one word, not sentences. I need help with the sentences. See the code above.

Comment: Please describe why it doesn't work for sentences and/or what specific problem you have trying to implement it to work with sentences. "It doesn't work" is generally not a good problem description. And please fix up the indentation to make the code readable.

Comment: Have you tried putting what you already have into a loop?

Comment: What ` `enter code here` ` is supposed to do? I suspect that its a comment.

Comment: You need to be careful about variable initialisation. If you enter a word without a "vowel", say "sky" or "lynx", `x` is not initialised and may have a garbage value.

Comment: And, the code won't work if the whole word is entered in Uppercase. I am not sure if thats what you require though.

Answer (score 0):

In your do..while loop I can see a for loop like this,

```
for(y=0;y<length;y++)
if(isvowel(word[y]))
{
    x=y;
    break;
}
```

Is this supposed to be

```
for(y=0;y<length;y++)  
{  
    if(isvowel(word[y]))  
    {  
        x=y;  
        break;  
    }  
}
```

The way I see it, you haven't initialized `y` to any value till `for(y=0;y<length;y++)` and then through this `for` loop you increment the value of `y` to `length-1`, thats where I assume that you want to check every `y`th index of array `word` and break out of `for` loop if its a vowel.

It generates the following output:

```
Translating English words to Pig Latin


Enter your English word:Apple
eApplay

Press ~ to exit

Enter your word:
Enter your English word:AppleCut
eCutApplay

Press ~ to exit

Enter your word:
Enter your English word:
```